# Compare created_at to an hours_old integer in JsonField in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm trying to create a django query that compares my models `created_at` date to see if they are at least x hours old where x is defined in a nested JsonField `hours_old`.

So for example:

```py
# This creates a timedelta ("Duration" natively, I think)
hours_past = ExpressionWrapper(
    timezone.now() - F('created_at'),
    output_field=DateTimeField()
)

Person.objects.annotate(
    hours_old=F('settings__json__data__hours_old') # Let's say this is an int of 3
    hours_past=hours_past # Let's say this is a timedelta of 2 days
).filter(
    hours_old__lt=F('hours_past') # I want 3 < 48
)
```

But I can't compare a time duration to a random int obviously. What's the play here?

Using `django==3.2.5`

Comment: You need to express the hours_past timedelta as a number of hours. I don't have a django application or PG database operating at the moment, so I can't remember the best way to do this, but I expect there's some call you can add to the ExpressionWrapper to convert the timedelta to a number of hours.

Comment: I've tried using the `ExtractHours(hours_past)` database method. Not sure that's what I actually want, and it seems to always return zero.

Answer (score 0):

If `created_at` is a timestamp, `hours_past` results in a `timedelta`/`interval` and its [`output_field`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/#output-field) should be a [`DurationField()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#durationfield) instead:

```python
hours_past = ExpressionWrapper(
    timestamp.now() - F('created_at'), #10am-9am=1hour, not 1am
    output_field=DurationField()       #timedelta/interval
)
```

For your filter, you can convert one:

```python
Person.objects.annotate(
    hours_old=F('settings__json__data__hours_old') #3 hours
    hours_past=hours_past                          #2 days
).filter(
    hours_old__lt=hours_past/timedelta(hours=1)
)
```

Or the other

```python
Person.objects.annotate(
    hours_old=F('settings__json__data__hours_old') #3 hours
    hours_past=hours_past                          #2 days
).filter(
    hours_past__gte=timedelta(hours=hours_old)
)
```

Comment: Should probably mention I'm on `django==3.2.5`. When I set the output field to DurationField() I get the error: `DurationField object has no attribute 'get_internal_type'`  
As for the conversions, I can do something like `hours_old__lt=5` but to put an annotated field on the other side of the equals I need to use `F('hours_past')` which doesn't seem like it works with these conversion strategies. `unsupported type for timedelta hours component: F`

Comment: Also `hours_past/timedelta(hours=1)` gives the error operator does not exist: interval / interval.  
I tried `hours_past__gt=hours_old*timedelta(hours=1)` and it said operator does not exist: jsonb * interval.  
Is this an issue with django not full recognizing this as an integer? In python debug it shows hours_old as an int

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Thanks to Zegarek and lxop for the inspiration!

```py
    delta_since_created = ExpressionWrapper(
        timezone.now() - F('created_at'),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
    
    hours_delta = ExpressionWrapper(
        Cast(F('settings__json__data__hours_old'), IntegerField()) * timedelta(hours=1),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
    
    people = Person.objects.annotate(
        hours_delta=hours_delta
    ).filter(
        hours_delta__lt=delta_since_created
    )
```

Seems casting `timedelta` to `DateTimeField` creates a `DurationField`. The json was being turned into an int after the query ran, but not during. Comparisons and math were failing until I cast it to an `IntegerField` manually.